# Sql case not returning values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to choose between two select staments based on number of results. Each statement returns valid data when tested outside the following case statement.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Count(base.id) > 0 THEN base.id 
         ELSE (SELECT id 
               FROM   tablea 
               WHERE  pid = @val) 
       END 
FROM   (SELECT id 
        FROM   tablea 
        WHERE  id = @val) AS base
```

When base.Id >0 it retuns correct, otherwise Null when instead it should have 7 rows from my table

Comment: You want to return null or 7 other rows?

Comment: That looks unusually complex - why isn't it just `WHERE id = @val or pid = @val` in a simple `select`?

Comment: The OR returns all values which apply. I only want one condition true with id being the primary condition. Sorry I was not so clear

Answer (score 4):

`WHEN COUNT(base.id) >0` is always true, because your `FROM` filters out rows where id <>@val. Unless I misunderstood what you want, the following gives you desired results:

```
SELECT id               
FROM   tablea 
WHERE  id = @val OR pid = @val
```

**Update :**

```
SELECT id               
FROM   tablea 
WHERE  id = @val OR (pid = @val 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tablea WHERE id = @val))
```

Comment: I want only rows where id= @val if there are none I wish to return only rows where pid=@val

Comment: So in the ELSE case it performs a new query with a different FROM clause

Comment: @user13186 check Alex07's [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6b68/1).. ;) +1 Alex07. When [keyword search for comments, questions, answers for entire site is ready I am going to put your answer in brilliant folder :)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords/161869#161869)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to select one set of rows or, failing that, a second set.  One way is to `union` the two sets and then pick what you want:

```
select id from (
  select id, 1 as Selector
    from tablea
    where id = @val
  union
  select id, 2
    from tablea
    where pid = @val ) as Placeholder
  where Selector = case when exists ( select 42 from tablea where id = @val ) then 1 else 2 end
```

I have assumed that `id` is not nullable.

Comment: Yes you are correct I am looking for one set or the other but due the tables size I fear a union query would take too long due to finding both sets every time. Is it the only way?

Comment: You could simply do an `if exists ( select 42 from tablea where id = @val )` to decide which query to execute, but you seemed to have your heart set on doing it in one swell foop.

Comment: this all happens during a select command onPage load & the value of @val will actually be another nested query causing horrible rutime. This has been a good help though. Thanks

Comment: @user13186 - Have you checked the usual suspects for performance problems?  Examine the execution plans, check indexes, update index statistics, ... .  Do you need real-time results or could you use a cached result that is up to, say, 5 minutes old?

Comment: Can't cache and @val is equal to a three level recursion so I think as long as I get it under 30 sec it just is what it is.